# Cloud Functions for Firebase - Remove oldest child

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a onWrite cloud function set up to listen for when a user updates something. I'm trying to delete the oldest child if there are more than 3, this is there I'm at:

```
exports.removeOld = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/media').onWrite(event => {

    const uid = event.params.uid

    if(event.data.numChildren() > 3) {
        //Remove Oldest child...
    }

})
```

Each of these children has a `"timestamp"` key.

```
{
  "users" : {
    "jKAWX7v9dSOsJtatyHHXPQ3MO193" : {
      "media" : {
        "-Kq2_NvqCXCg_ogVRvA" : {
          "date" : 1.501151203274347E9,
          "title" : "Something..."
        },
        "-Kq2_V3t_kws3vlAt6B" : {
          "date" : 1.501151232526373E9,
          "title" : "Hello World.."
        }
        "-Kq2_V3t_kws3B6B" : {
          "date" : 1.501151232526373E9,
          "title" : "Hello World.."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So in the above example, when the text value is added to "media", the oldest would be delete.

Comment: can you add the structure of firebase childs?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

[This sample should help you.](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/limit-children)

You need something like that :

```
const MAX_LOG_COUNT = 3;

exports.removeOld = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/media/{mediaId}').onCreate(event => {
    const parentRef = event.data.ref.parent;

    return parentRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.numChildren() >= MAX_LOG_COUNT) {
            let childCount = 0;

            const updates = {};

            snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
                if (++childCount <= snapshot.numChildren() - MAX_LOG_COUNT) {
                    updates[child.key] = null;
                }
            });

            // Update the parent. This effectively removes the extra children.
            return parentRef.update(updates);
        }
    });
});
```

[You can find all Cloud Functions for Firebase samples here.](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples)