# Optimising Firebase database by automatically overwriting data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Firebase app I have the following structure:

- ***Posts***

  - ***Latest***

All users can write to **Posts** **> Latest**. I want to limit entries to 20 posts to save space in the database. And posts beyond 20 are unnecessary as they will never be shown on the homepage.

How can I limit the posts to 20, so that when a user writes to **Posts > Latest** the posts at the end will drop off (be deleted) automatically?

Comment: Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45348229/3222713

Answer (score 0):

[This sample should help you.](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/limit-children)

You need something like that :

```
const MAX_LOG_COUNT = 20;

exports.removeOld = functions.database.ref('/Posts/Latest/{postId}').onCreate(event => {
    const parentRef = event.data.ref.parent;

    return parentRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.numChildren() >= MAX_LOG_COUNT) {
            let childCount = 0;

            const updates = {};

            snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
                if (++childCount <= snapshot.numChildren() - MAX_LOG_COUNT) {
                    updates[child.key] = null;
                }
            });

            // Update the parent. This effectively removes the extra children.
            return parentRef.update(updates);
        }
    });
});
```

[You can find all Cloud Functions for Firebase samples here.](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples)